# How to echo value from a different table?

Tags: php, mysql

Here's a very simplified example of what I am trying to achieve :

```
USERS
 id      |    name          
 12      |    Phil      

ACTIONS
 sender  |  recipient
 12      |  Alice

$table = query("SELECT id, sender FROM users WHERE recipient = Alice");
foreach ($table as $row) {
$sender = $row['sender'];

echo '$sender has sent a gift to Alice';
}
```

This will output :

```
12 sent a gift to Alice
```

How can I get the below output instead ?

```
**Phil** sent a gift to Alice
```

Should I join the two tables ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a join:

```
SELECT u.name, sender
FROM actions a join
     users u
     on a.sender = u.id
WHERE recipient = 'Alice';
```